# Weird (?) NDSolve behavior at boundary

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I'm trying to numerical solve the following differential equation (also described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524407/second-order-non-linear-differential-equation-with-polynomial-of-the-derivative)):

$$ c_1 (y(x)-1)y'(x) - (c_2 x + x^3 (c_3y(x)-c_4))y'(x)^2+c_5 x^3y'(x)^3 + xy''(x)(y(x)-1)(c_6 + x^2(c_7y(x) - c_8))=0$$

which should admit a cdf $y(x)$, with non-negative density $y'(x)$ on it's entire support.

```
eq = 2.4 (-1 + y[x]) Derivative[1][y][
  x] - (1.2 x - 2.28 x^3 + 2.1 x^3 y[x]) Derivative[1][y][x]^2 + 
0.24 x^3 Derivative[1][y][x]^3 + 
x (-1 + y[x]) (1.2 - 0.88 x^2 + 0.7 x^2 y[x]) Derivative[2][y][x] == 0;
s = NDSolveValue[{eq, y[1.2] == 1, y[.7] == 0}, y, {x, .7, 1.2}];
Plot[s'[x], {x, 1.1, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

which yields

[image]

Conversely,

```
s2 = NDSolveValue[{eq, y[1.2] == .999, y[.7] == 0}, y, {x, .4, 1.2}];
Plot[s2'[x], {x, 1.1, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

yields the much smoother

[image]

What goes wrong if I set the 'true' boundary condition $y(1.2)=1$?

Comment: The ODE is singular at `y[x] == 1`, as can be seen from examining the coefficient of `y''[x]`.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no 'true' solution for this ODE, or simply that numerical methods won't be able to find it?

Comment: Nonlinear ODEs can have many solutions, or no solutions, depending on boundary conditions.  For instance, `y[x] == 1` is a solution of the general equation, but not with your particular boundary conditions.  I shall give this more this more thought later today.

Comment: If my ODE would have multiple solutions, can I also find the other ones using ndsolve? The one currently obtained doesn't really make sense ($(y(x)=1$ for $x$ large enough, although the derivative is non-zero).

Comment: What boundary conditions would you impose on other solutions?

Comment: The same that I currently have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rationalize the equation and increase the working precision, and you will get a smooth curve, but it also shows that the y is going to 0 for your range of x.

```
eq = 2.4 (-1 + y[x]) Derivative[1][y][
      x] - (1.2 x - 2.28 x^3 + 2.1 x^3 y[x]) Derivative[1][y][x]^2 + 
    0.24 x^3 Derivative[1][y][x]^3 + 
    x (-1 + y[x]) (1.2 - 0.88 x^2 + 0.7 x^2 y[x]) Derivative[2][y][
      x] == 0 // Rationalize;

s = NDSolveValue[{eq, y[1.2] == 1, y[.7] == 0}, y, {x, .7, 1.2},WorkingPrecision -> 50];

Plot[s'[x], {x, 1.1, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The higher the WorkingPrecision, the smaller the values.

Comment: It's true that the resulting curve is smooth, but several orders of magnitude off the results obtained from setting $y(1.2)=.99999$.

Comment: But if you keep increasing the number of 9's, the numbers keep getting smaller and smaller also

Comment: @bonifaz  It appears that there is no solution that goes exactly to `1` at `x == 1.2`, although one can get arbitrarily close.  The solution in the answer above loses precision at about `x == 1.15; y == 10^-26`.

Comment: So does this mean that this problem doesn't have a 'true' solution? Or just none that can be computed properly?

Comment: I guess I could do the following: Near the singularity of $y(1.2)=1$, I use the  first order DE (that eventually generates my final second order ODE) to describe the local behavior of $y$. And then I use ndsolve with boundary condition e.g. $y(1.15)=.99$. Would that be permissable, or would this just cover something that the actual singularity would tell me otherwise?

Comment: @bonifaz  Your question is difficult to answer without more details.  With respect to your earlier comment, I do not believe the your original ODE has a second solution exactly satisfying the two boundary conditions.

Answer (score 5):

This is, to me at least, an interesting and somewhat unusual ODE.

**Higher Precision Solution**

The ODE is singular at `y[x] == 1`, which acts as an attractor when approached from below.  Consequently, there appears to be no solution that goes exactly to 1 at x == 1.2, although some can be arbitrarily close.  For instance, in the solution given by [Bill Watts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53121/bill-watts),

```
s = NDSolveValue[{eq, y[7/10] == 0, y[12/10] == 1}, y, {x, 7/10, 12/10}, 
    MaxSteps -> 10^6, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
Plot[s[x], {x, .7, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], ImageSize -> Large]
LogPlot[s'[x], {x, .7, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y'}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

[image]

`y'[x]` decreases approximately exponentially as `x` approaches `1.2`, losing precision at about y[1.15] == 10^-27`.  Note that the slope of`y[x]`at`x == 0.7` is

```
s'[7/10]
(* 4.93285063801117625190985639916133706 *)
```

A likely course of action to obtain a solution approaching y[1.2] == 1 more rapidly is to increase the initial slope and use a larger `WorkingPrecision`.  The built-in "Shooting" method often does not work well with such nonlinear threshold problems, but trial-and-error often does.  For instance, with an initial slope of 5.04,

```
s = NDSolveValue[{eq, y[7/10] == 0, y'[7/10] == 504/100}, y, {x, 7/10, 12/10},  
    MaxSteps -> 10^6, WorkingPrecision -> 180, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
Plot[s[x], {x, .7, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], ImageSize -> Large]
LogPlot[s'[x], {x, .7, 1.2}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y'}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

[image]

Although the solution may appear to have a discontinuous slope at about `x == .9014`, expanding the plots near there shows that the curves vary smoothly, and that `y'[x]` decays approximately exponentially, finally losing precision at a value of about `10^-110`, which probably is sufficiently close to zero.  Note that `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` is used to avoid the somewhat mysterious `NDSolveValue::nderr` error.  Also, the corresponding computation with an  initial slope of `5.05` or larger fails, because the `y'[x]` becomes infinite before the curve reaches `y[x] == 1`.

**Search for Alternative Solutions**

Because the ODE is nonlinear, it is possible that other solutions approaching `y[1.2] == 1` at large angles may exist.  Before conducting a search, it is useful to observe that the ODE has a second curve on which the coefficient of `y''[x]` vanishes.

```
ss = Flatten@Solve[(1.2 - 0.88 x^2 + 0.7 x^2 y[x]) == 0 // Rationalize, y[x]] // Values
(* {(4 (-15 + 11 x^2))/(35 x^2)} *)
```

This curve crosses `y[x] == 1` at `x == 2 Sqrt[5/3]`.  Now perform a sweep of initial slopes.

```
sp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, y[7/10] == 0, y'[7/10] == yp}, y, {x, 7/10, 30/10}, {yp}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 60, MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
Show[Plot[Evaluate@Table[sp[yp][x], {yp, -8, 5, 1/5}], {x, 7/10, 30/10}, 
         PlotRange -> {-1.2, 1.2}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
         LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium]],
     Plot[{ss, 1}, {x, 7/10, 30/10}, PlotRange -> All, 
         PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed]], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

The ODE can be integrated through the singular curve (shown as a dashed line), because `y'[x] == 0` on the singular curve for the solutions computed.  Incidentally, curves integrated from, for instance, `y[.7] == - 1/10` also pass smoothly through the singular curve, again with `y'[x] == 0`.  Hence, defining initial conditions `{y[x], y'[x]}` on the singular surface is not sufficient to determine unique solutions originating there.  Returning to the original issue, we see that there is no other family of solutions approaching `y[1.2] == 1`.